# Vaadin How to SelectAll() in ComboBox field?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Vaadin 7.6.2

What's the best approach to performing a selectAll() in ComboBox field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean selecting all text in the input field of a `ComboBox`, there is no a build-in support for that.

The most elegant solution would be to create your own Vaadin extension, which would provide server-side API for selecting text in a `ComboBox`.

The easiest but a bit hackish solution is to defined a unique id for your `ComboBox`:

```
comboBox.setId("my-combobox");
```

and use the JavaScript API of Vaadin to execute a JavaScript snippet that selects text on client side:

```
JavaScript.eval("setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('my-combobox').firstChild.select(); }, 0);");
```

I tested this quickly, and it seemed to work in Chrome, Safari and Firefox at least.

Comment: Doesn't work.  I've applied setId() on my fields and when I run that JavaScript.eval method against one of those IDs, nothing happens.  Is there another step I'm missing?  (using Safari)

Comment: That's weird, I tested again and works fine on OS X Safari. What's your use case, in which situation you need to do the selection?

Comment: Actually, it seems to work, but not consistently, which is weird.  Turns out that I can live without it for now, but would like to see Vaadin folks implement selectAll() on ComboBoxes.

Comment: I improved the JS inside the eval a bit, maybe it helps to make it work consistently. If you want, you could create a ticket about this feature request to https://dev.vaadin.com/. Thanks!

Comment: Still doesn't work and no idea why.  If I get rid of "firstChild" it sorta behaves like it wants to work, but doesn't really.  Appreciate you effort however. +1

Comment: Not sure what happened, but it actually DOES work.  Thanks.